# Add-to-timeline deprecation on Facebook. How to replace it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, button, user-interface, facebook-timeline

According to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/), the "Add to Timeline" button will be deprecated as of August 2012.  Unfortunately, there is no guidance on how to achieve the same functionality.  Perplexingly, the [Open Graph tutorial](http://hhttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ttp://) uses the button (which seems unwise given that it will be broken in a couple months).  Since I'm writing a new implementation of actions/timeline right now, I'm not going to include something that I'll have to delete in a couple months.  Everything works fine with AJAX and the PHP-SDK and only two issues remain unresolved (which I imagine the button would handle):

1. No way to tell if an action is posted already.  I have "unique" enabled already but I have no way to hide the "Add to timeline" option if it's already posted.
2. No nice visual.  I could render the current (soon to be deprecated) button and steal the image but I'd prefer to use something that will look the same as other sites and make users comfortable that they know what will happen when they click.

Does Facebook have a replacement for this button?  Or are all timeline posts supposed to be taking place silently after an initial permission grant?  I thought Facebook encouraged more user approval for Timeline actions--where is that control supposed to go?  To third party UI elements?  Doesn't that undermine some of the power of the Facebook ecosystem--the fact that it's the same buttons with the same behavior everywhere on the web?  It's kind of frustrating the way it's presented now--pushing you in one direction in the tutorial only to tell you that the feature will be deprecated within months.  I've mostly given up hope for problem #1 but is there an official non-deprecated button that will give me a nice comforting visual?

Also, are there other features that this button does that are being/have been transitioned to other plugins?

EDIT: Does it make sense to link the "Like" button to a timeline event?  It seems like semantically that would make sense but there doesn't seem to be any built-in way to do it.